# How to use Apache ActiveMQ Artemis in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, activemq-artemis, kubernetes-networking, artemiscloud

I have an issue where I have a workload in Kubernetes which contains an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker. The server starts properly when I have a single pod in my workload, the issue starts when I try to scale them. The brokers in the pods can't connect to each other, so I can't scale my work load. My final goal is to make it scalable. I tried it locally with two docker containers and it worked fine.

Here is my `broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <name>Broker1</name>

        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="brokerCluster-broadcast">
                <local-bind-address>0.0.0.0</local-bind-address>
                <local-bind-port>10000</local-bind-port>
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <broadcast-period>20</broadcast-period>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="brokerCluster-discovery">
                <local-bind-port>10000</local-bind-port>
                <local-bind-address>0.0.0.0</local-bind-address>
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <refresh-timeout>10</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="brokerCluster">
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="brokerCluster-discovery"/>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61610</connector>
        </connectors>

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

        <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

        <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

        <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <journal-buffer-timeout>536000</journal-buffer-timeout>

        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


        <page-sync-timeout>536000</page-sync-timeout>

        <acceptors>

            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61610</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

        </acceptors>


        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>

        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="TestQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="testQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Edit: Attached kubernetes,docker configs

**deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: artemis
  labels:
    app: artemis
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6161
    name: service
    protocol: UDP
  - port: 8161
    name: console
    protocol: UDP
  - port: 9876
    name: broadcast
    protocol: UDP
  - port: 61610
    name: netty-connector
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 5672
    name: acceptor-amqp
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 61613
    name: acceptor-stomp
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 5445
    name: accep-hornetq
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 1883
    name: acceptor-mqt
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 10000
    protocol: UDP
    name: brokercluster-broadcast // this name is invalid but i wanted to match it to my broker.xml
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: artemis01
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: artemis01headless
  namespace: artemis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: artemis01 
  serviceName: artemis01
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: artemis01 
    spec:
      affinity:
          nodeAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - worker
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: ARTEMIS_PASSWORD
            value: admin
          - name: ARTEMIS_USER
            value: admin
          - name: MY_POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          name: artemis
          image: 
          ports:
          - containerPort: 6161
            name: service
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 8161
            name: console
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 9876
            name: broadcast
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 61610
            name: netty-connector
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 5672
            name: acceptor-amqp
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 61613
            name: acceptor-stomp
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 5445
            name: accep-hornetq
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 1883
            name: acceptor-mqtt
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 10000
            name: brokercluster-broadcast
            protocol: UDP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: xxxxxxx
```

[**Dockerfile** source](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/artemis-docker)

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

# ActiveMQ Artemis

FROM jboss/base-jdk:8
LABEL maintainer="Apache ActiveMQ Team"
# Make sure pipes are considered to determine success, see: https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL4006
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
WORKDIR /opt

ENV ARTEMIS_USER artemis
ENV ARTEMIS_PASSWORD artemis
ENV ANONYMOUS_LOGIN false
ENV CREATE_ARGUMENTS --user ${ARTEMIS_USER} --password ${ARTEMIS_PASSWORD} --silent --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia

USER root

# add user and group for artemis
RUN groupadd -g 1001 -r artemis && useradd -r -u 1001 -g artemis artemis \
 && yum install -y libaio && yum -y clean all

USER artemis

ADD . /opt/activemq-artemis

# Web Server
EXPOSE 8161 \
    61610 \
    9876 \
    61613 \
    61616 \
    5672 \
    5445 \
    1883 \
    10000

USER root

RUN mkdir /var/lib/artemis-instance && chown -R artemis.artemis /var/lib/artemis-instance

COPY ./docker/docker-run.sh /

USER artemis

# Expose some outstanding folders
VOLUME ["/var/lib/artemis-instance"]
WORKDIR /var/lib/artemis-instance

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-run.sh"]
CMD ["run"]
```

**run.sh**

```sh
set -e

BROKER_HOME=/var/lib/
CONFIG_PATH=$BROKER_HOME/etc
export BROKER_HOME OVERRIDE_PATH CONFIG_PATH

echo CREATE_ARGUMENTS=${CREATE_ARGUMENTS}

if ! [ -f ./etc/broker.xml ]; then
    /opt/activemq-artemis/bin/artemis create ${CREATE_ARGUMENTS} .
    #the script copies my broker.xml to /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/broker.xml here.
    sed -i -e 's|$PLACEHOLDERIP|'$MY_POD_IP'|g' /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/broker.xml
else
    echo "broker already created, ignoring creation"
fi

exec ./bin/artemis "$@"
```

Comment: *"The server starts properly when I have a single pod in my workload, the issue starts when I try to scale them."* - How do you scale them ? Do you use `Deployment` or `StatefulSet` ? As this is a `Stateful` application, [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) should be used for deploying it. There is even a ready [helmchart](https://mailrucloudsolutions.github.io/activemq-artemis-helm/), so you can use it or simply take a look at it to compare how everything should be set up.

Comment: The helm chart is sadly out dated, and it's repo no longer exists. Now i changed to stateful set but the dns can't be resolved between the pods.

Comment: Did you try to deploy anything else on this kubernetes cluster ? Does the `Pods` communicate with each other without any issues ? Could you provide any details about your cluster ? What is the **kukbernetes version** you're using ? How was it **set up** ? What **CNI** are you using ? Are those `Pods` deployed on a single or separate nodes ? So far it looks more like an issue with `activemq-artemis` configuration. If you've already managed to resolve it, please update your question.

Comment: So multicast/UDP on k8s is where your problem is. Try using Jgroups and it will find each other.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with your `connector` configuration. This is what you're using:

```xml
<connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61610</connector>
```

The information from this connector gets broadcast to the other cluster members since you've specified it in the `<connector-ref>` of your `<cluster-connection>`. The other cluster members then try to use this information to connect back to the node that broadcast it. However, 0.0.0.0 won't make sense to a remote client.

The address 0.0.0.0 is a meta-address. In the context of a listener (e.g. an Artemis `acceptor`) it means that the listener will listen for connections on all local addresses. In the context of a `connector` it doesn't really have a meaning. See [this article for more about 0.0.0.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0).

You should be using a *real* IP address or hostname that a client can use to actually get a network route to the server.

Also, since you're using UDP multicast (i.e. via the `<broadcast-group>` and `<discovery-group>`) please ensure this functions as well between the containers/pods. If you can't get UDP multicast working in your environment (or simply don't want to) you could switch to a static cluster configuration. Refer to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#discovery-using-static-connectors) and [the "clustered static discovery" example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery) for details on how to configure this.

Comment: I tried it with real ips but they still can't connect to each other.

Comment: It's hard to comment without additional troubleshooting information. Are the IP addresses you're using actually reachable from the other container/pod via `ping` (or something similar)? Also, since you're using UDP multicast that will have to be enabled between the containers/pods as well. Otherwise you could switch to a static cluster configuration.

Comment: I added my docker file, kubernetes configs, yes i can reach other pods, i can even use telnet for the specified port.

Comment: Can you confirm that UDP multicast is working between them as well? Have you tried a static cluster configuration? I'm not terribly familiar with Kubernetes and docker so I'm not sure if opening the ports is enough to enable UDP multicast given that it's almost never supported in any kind of cloud environment.

Comment: @JustinBertram UDP/Multicast on K8s is the problem. AFAIK UDP will only work on a node i.e. if the two pods are on different nodes the multicast is broken. HOwever JGroups has an excellent  solution for this.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I gave the questioner the benefit of the doubt that UDP was the right choice for their use-case. ActiveMQ Artemis has integration with JGroups for situations like this so ultimately it shouldn't be a problem.